# Два вопроса по редактору DraftJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В react приложении сделан редактор DraftJS. Есть два вопроса:

1. К редактору DraftJS подключен плагин дивидеров. Но в нем только одна кнопка. Как сделать вторую? Плагин вот этот https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/divider.
2. Как добавить пикер в уже установленный плагин со смайлами. Пикер нужен вот этот: https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart.

Заранее спасибо если кто то сможет подсказать